# glb mesh disappears on rotation threejs

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I've dug around looking for a solve for this - but couldn't find the answer on here. I have a gltf/glb model loading into three js as such:

```
  createScene: function() {

  this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
  this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  this.renderer.setClearColor(new Three.Color('#fff'));
  this.renderer.setClearAlpha( 0 );
  //this.render.shadowMap.type = Three.PCFSoftShadowMap;
  container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
},
createCamera: function() {
  this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(6, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
  this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);
},
createShape: function() {
    let me = this;
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'model/fbf3.glb', function ( gltf ) {
        me.bottle = gltf.scene
        me.scene.add( gltf.scene );
        gltf.scene.traverse(function(obj) { obj.frustumCulled = false; });
        me.pivot = new Three.Group();
        me.pivot.position.set( 0.0, 0.0, 0 );
        me.bottle.add( me.pivot );
        console.log(gltf.scene);
        console.log(gltf.scene.children[1]);
        
        //me.pivot.add( me.bottle );
        me.animate();
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    });
},
```

I found a post that said to loop through the scene and be sure to add frustumCulled to false - so that's added in ( and when I log the child, that objects frustumCulled is set to false ). In order to have a label on my object easy to map and also take on a different material/glossiness i've created another object in the group that is just slightly in front of my other object on the yaxis. When it is facing the camera, it works well - however, it is when the object rotates is where it disappears. Working:

[image: front]

Rotate enough, and gone:
[image: back]

Is there a setting in threejs that I need to add to be sure the render order is correct? Or is it something wrong with my object set up in Blender? Ideally I wouldn't have to UV wrap the whole bottle as one object and add the label to the bottle texture because I want the label to have less specularity ( that a word? ). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And when added to donmccurdy's gltf viewer - it behaves the same way. Changing the double sided to 1.0 on the object that has the label in blender before export shows the back of the mesh with the material - however it still behaves the same way on rotation - the part that should be rendered disappears.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is alpha blending.  Making the bottle partially transparent prevents the use of the Z buffer for correct depth ordering.  But the label shouldn't be transparent, right?  What happens if the label's material is set to fully opaque, does that fix it?

Comment: I'm using this as a tutorial: https://medium.com/@matthewmain/how-to-import-a-3d-blender-object-into-a-three-js-project-as-a-gltf-file-5a67290f65f2

I'm trying to only append from the pbr/node tree - which includes AlphaBlend, AlphaMask, Emissive, glTF Metallic Roughness, Glossiness, and Occlusion. Using Roughness or Glosiness results in the issue - whether i make doublesided 0 or 100. I have tried using AlphaMask and that works as expected, however it is simply a white texture without the image applied on export despite linking the image texture > alpha blends shader > material surface.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - the tutorial is slightly old ( 2+years ) and now Blender ( the latest version 2.9+ ) has the Principled BSDF Shader baked in. Instead of using the glTF-Blender-Exporter-Master pbr appended shaders from the listed tutorial - I instead used the Principled BSDF Shader - linked my material to it's Base Color and linked that to the Material Output ( all in the node/now Shader Editor. No issues anymore.